# Adding constraints to views programmatically using ConstraintSet does not give expected result in Android?

Tags: android

I have a custom ConstraintLayout, and there's a TextView inside of it. I'm doing everything programmatically **WITHOUT XML** at all, here's the code:

```
public class CustomView extends ConstraintLayout {
    private TextView textView;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        textView.setText("...");

        // Adding border to the view in order to visualize the frame
        GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
        border.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        border.setStroke(1, Color.BLACK);
        textView.setBackground(border);
        addView(textView);

        // Apply constraints to textView. Left = right = top = bottom = 120

        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(this);
        set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 120);
        set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 120);
        set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 120);
        set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 120);
        set.applyTo(this);
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I'm getting some wrong results:

1. If the text in textView is short:

[image]

2. If the text in textView is long:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct that your wrong result - you don't see the margins?
I think this because defaults `layout_width` `layout_height` of your textview - wrap_content. Defaults must be **0dp**. 
Try like:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(0, 0);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem. New to Android and I'd say 99.99% Android developer out there use XML to set up views. I came from iOS and never ever had to configure views with my mouse, therefore I wish to do the same in Android. Your answer helps big time, thanks again.